# Передача найденных совпадений в конструктор

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Написал код для авторизации через mdb, но мне необходимо передать в конструктор формы **tf** логин, который соответствует ID для регистрации. Как мне это осуществить?

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\SAIBERPRO\Мои документы\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ЭУП (Чанов А)\WindowsFormsApplication4\AppTest\AppTest\Base.mdb");
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select ID From AuthTable where Login ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
// Проверяем, что количество строк из БД больше нуля
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
       // Нужный Вам ID
       string ID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
       this.Hide();
       TestForm tf = new TestForm(); // Сюда передать Login
       tf.Show();
}
else
{
      MessageBox.Show("Неправильно введённые имя или пароль");
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `TestForm tf = new TestForm(textBox1.Text);` ?

Comment: Вопрос решил, до меня только сейчас дошло что DataTable то двумерный массив а я обращался как к одномерному. Выборку надо всех делать "Select * From AuthTable where Login ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", connection). А передавать в конструктор следующую колонку в таблице dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()